# Numpy get elements by incrementing the index of element

Tags: numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,13,7,3,5])
index = a == 13
print a[index+1]
```

The expected result is 7. How to get?

Answer (score 1):

#### Foreword

My proposed solutions are a generalization of the OP question, because the OP array had just an occurrence of the number `13` and here I treat the possibility of having more than a single occurrence.

All my solutions except one are based on the idea of the circularity of a list (as is made more clear by the name `rotate` that I've used for my helper function).

If there are use cases (I think there are such use cases)! where the assumption of circularity is not welcome, then use either my third piece of code or, better, the answer from @cel provided that you test the index before accessing the array or include the access in a `try` `except` clause.

#### Code Chunks

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,13,7,3,5])
>>> i = a == 13
>>> print a[np.concatenate(([False],i[:-1]))]
[7]
>>>
```

another possibility

```
>>> print a[np.concatenate((i[-1:],i[:-1]))]
[7]
>>>
```

another one (fragile, it can index beyond the length of `a`, don't use this last one in this bare format, see foreword)

```
>>> print a[np.arange(len(a))[i]+1]
[7]
>>>
```

You have now an *array* of possibilities...

#### Elegance?

```
>>> def rotate(a,n):
...     n = n%len(a) 
...     return np.concatenate((a[-n:],a[:-n]))
...
>>> print a[rotate(i,1)]
[7]
>>>
```

Comment: is not there more straightforeword and elegant way?

Comment: `index` aka `i` is not an integer index into `a`, have you tried `print index` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `nonzero`.  It returns a tuple of arrays, so you have to do some extra indexing:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([1,2,13,7,3,5])

In [2]: i = a == 13

In [3]: i
Out[3]: array([False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [4]: i.nonzero()
Out[4]: (array([2]),)

In [5]: i.nonzero()[0]
Out[5]: array([2])

In [6]: i.nonzero()[0][0]
Out[6]: 2

In [7]: a[i.nonzero()[0][0] + 1]
Out[7]: 7
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,13,7,3,5])
indices, = np.where(a[:-1] == 13)
print a[indices[0] + 1]
```

In python3 you can also do:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,13,7,3,5])
indices, = np.where(a[:-1] == 13)
first_index, *_ = indices
print(a[first_index + 1])
```

Which in my opinion is more readable. Unfortunately, extended tuple unpacking is not supported in python2 versions.

Both versions require that the problem is well defined and there is indeed a `13` in the list and that it has a predecessor.
If this does not hold for your problem, the length of `indices` can be checked and in case of length `0` you may want to terminate with an appropriate error.

Comment: As usual, answers that attack _the problem_ rather than _the question_ are the better ones.

Comment: But what happens if `a = np.array((7,3,5,1,2,13))`?

Comment: @gboffi you mean a two dimensional array? Why would I want to write a somewhat less readable solution for a problem that is only defined on one-dimensional arrays?

Comment: No, in my example `a` is still 1D: `np.array` mandatory argument is a sequence of objects, it's indifferent if it's a list (OP) or a tuple (my comment). That said, what about the case in which only the last element of `a` is equal to 13?

Comment: @gboffi I don't understand your first point. I agree with the second one. But there is no need to sacrifice readability for this case. It should be fine to just write `np.where(a[:-1], 13)`

Comment: 1st point: 1D arrays can be created using different syntaxes. 2nd point, you should warn the OP, or the casual reader, of the possible failure path of your solution, so that the user code can provide for some kind of workaround. In other words, please explicitly tell in your answer that it doesn't work for a specific, rare possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most direct way:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,13,7,3,5])
print a[np.flatnonzero(a == 13) + 1]
```